# pdf invoice in node.js

Tags: node.js, phantomjs, node-pdfkit

I want to create a pdf invoice which has a dynamic table i.e. items in that particular table can be 1 or 100.

Now my problem if the content of table is large so that it can not fit into a single page then i need to add new page automatically.
Right now i am using pdfkit which provide me addPage() function to add the page but it has some design constraints and some times it is very difficult to convert a particular design into pdf.

I am thinking about phantomjs but i am not sure about how it adds a new page dynamically

can someone has better soultion for this

Comment: If you split the wide table yourself into multiple tables, then this should work.

Comment: but that table is a dynamic table. i don't the size of items and importantly i don't know about the content of these items

Comment: Then you'll just have to try it. You can always calculate the size of elements on the page and figure out the cutoff which you're fine with.